# rails admin + carrierwave updating breaks the image url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I'm using Rails 5 with rails_admin and carrierwave gems.

I have a model `Photo` and and image uploader mounted on it (as per carrierwave documentation), looks roughly like this:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  belongs_to :project

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true
end
```

Given I have already some `Photo` objects created I can see a list of them in the `rails_admin` admin view.

And I start editing one of them
And I edit name
And I proceed to save it

Then rails admin fires some of it's magic and photo is being saved but after this action the image dissapears.

I have been digging a little in what request are being fired and `rails_admin` fires a `PUT` request with such params:

```
{
 "authenticity_token"=>"xxx",
 "photo"=>{
   "name"=>"test2",
   "description"=>"ewdeeweeefxxxwefwe",
   "project_id"=>"3",
   "image_cache"=>"",
   "main"=>"0",
   "about_us"=>"0"
},
"return_to"=>"http://localhost:3000/panel-admin/photo?model_name=photo", "_save"=>"", "model_name"=>"photo", "id"=>"29"}
```

and my `Photo` object is being update with not only `name` but also with `image_url` that of course overrides `Image` that already was mounted to the `Photo`

I have no idea why this is happening and how to prevent it.

Anyone might have encountered this issue and knows how to resolve it?

Comment: I think it might have to do something with image_cache, but was not able to fix the problem yet. Maybe `rails_admin` is not setting correct image_cache as a hidden form element in the edit view? will try to investigate it further

Answer (score 0):

I found that. When I uncomment my custom `filename` method in uploader, it works well.